# Read .Sql file stored in S3 containing a Select statements and excute the statement over Snowflake and generate a CSV file using a Glue Job

Tags: python, sql, amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aws-glue

I have the following scenario as below, could kindly help me on this:

1. The S3 bucket has a `test.Sql` file containing for example: `select 'Rony' as Name , '1000.45' as Salary, 'Manager' as Designation`
2. Have a Snowflake environment and connectivity

The Glue job in Python should read this file and execute the sql statement and send the output to the same bucket with result folder.

Comment: It sounds like you have been given an assignment for a course? We're happy to help if you have a _specific_ problem, but it's probably a good idea to try things yourself first.

Comment: Hi john i am able to access the file  and when i use sf_excute sql in glue job it thorws a literal error. In sql_command=" " if you are using double quotes the single quotes woudnt work and other way around

Comment: Can you post some code of what you've tried? You can read the file line by line in Python and send an execute for each line.